# How to catch all promises with axios.all?

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

I am scraping a web page using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio):
This web page has many links, while more load while scrolling down(like [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)).
I want to scrape each link **while** scrolling down until I reach the end.
This is a sample of my code:

```
cheerio = require('cheerio')
axios = require('axios')

function getLink(id) {
    return axios(options).then(function(response) {
        // Do stuff...
    })
}

function scrollDown() {
    axios(scrollOptions).then(function(response) {
        $ = cheerio.load(response['data'])
        isScrollFinished = ($('.page_more').length == 0)
        promises = []
        newLinks = $('.link') // Get the new links that were loaded while scrolling
        newLinks.each(function() {
            promises.push(getLink($(this).attr('id')))
        })
        axios.all(promises).then(responseArr => {
            if(isScrollFinished) {
                // Exit script
            }
        })
        if(!isScrollFinished) {
            scrollDown()
        }
    })
}

scrollDown()
```

The problem with this code is that sometimes it doesn't scrape all the links before I exit.
This is because the last axios.all only waits until all the links of the **last** scrolled page were scraped.
How do I fix this?

Comment: `// Do Stuff`  shows ambiguity. Is it purposely done to not show implementaion code, or is it actually that itself

Comment: It is purposely done to not show implementation of code and is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

I created the promises array as a static variable and only called axios.all on it when the scrolling reached the end:

```
cheerio = require('cheerio')
axios = require('axios')

function getLink(id) {
    return axios(options).then(function(response) {
        // Do stuff...
    })
}

function scrollDown() {
    if (typeof scrollDown.promises === 'undefined') { 
        scrollDown.promises = [] // Define static variable if undefined
    }
    axios(scrollOptions).then(function(response) {
        $ = cheerio.load(response['data'])
        isScrollFinished = ($('.page_more').length == 0)
        newLinks = $('.link') // Get the new links that were loaded while scrolling
        newLinks.each(function() {
            scrollDown.promises.push(getLink($(this).attr('id')))
        })
        if(isScrollFinished) {
            axios.all(scrollDown.promises).then(responseArr => {
                // Exit script
            })
        }
        else {
            scrollDown()
        }
    })
}

scrollDown()
```

Better solutions will gladly be accepted.